# jQuery UI Datepicker is larger when inside iFrame (wtf?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, datepicker

Go [here](http://thestrand.spin-demo.com) and click on the **check availability** in the sidebar(don't enter any date).

Now, try to pick a date from within the sidebar and also try to pick a date from within the page. You'll see that the one on the page - which is in an iFrame - is much larger.

Anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: What code am I going to include? All the classes involved with the calendar? ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the same font and font-size to have the datepickers to be the same size.

The JQuery UI is measured in 'em', which is based on the size of the font.

from http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

"1em is equal to the current font size. 2em means 2 times the size of the current font. E.g., if an element is displayed with a font of 12 pt, then '2em' is 24 pt. The 'em' is a very useful unit in CSS, since it can adapt automatically to the font that the reader uses"

Comment: Thanks man. I didn't know that the jQuery UI is measured in EM, this fixed it :)